# Multiline string containing #if in a new line inside a bigger #if conditional block

Tags: c#

I have some C# code that contains a multiline string (which is some code template) that has some lines starting with `#if something`. This is all working fine except if I wrap the whole C# class inside an actual condition `#if` `#endif`, in which case the compiler says "invalid preprocessor directive".

Code snippet:

```
#if WIN32
class Something {
    string s = @"
#if SOMETHING
#endif";
}
#endif
```

Is there a way to make this work?
I have thought about using a different character in my code template, and using replaces to fix it, but this is not a very good solution for me because it makes the code template harder to understand.

Comment: Looks like it's already noted by the c# language team - https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/1230

Comment: Thanks! I couldn't find that bug report, thanks. There is no suggested workaround, I guess I will have to accept the "replacement" workaround...

Comment: Or I can just split my multiline string into separate strings, so they would have a quote `"` at the beginning of the line.

Comment: @Lordalcol, A better approach would be to define Resources file.

Answer (score 1):

I would do the following:

```
const string hash = "#";

#if WIN32
class Something {
    string s = $@"
{hash}if SOMETHING
{hash}endif";
}
#endif
```

Comment: That should work, but it makes the code template in the string less readable.

Comment: Yes, but at least you won't need to worry about breaking the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

I think you put your " and ; at wrong places. This works fine without any complaints

```
#if DEBUG
class Something {
    readonly string s = @"
#if CODE_DEFINED_ONLY_IF_SET
public class IAmOnlyHappyWhenItRains{
    public int Year{get;set;}
    public string Name{get;set;}
}
#endif
";
}
#endif
```

Comment: although this example seems to work, but still the compiler tries to parse the contents of the string which can break things.

Comment: @Bizhan I am sorry I do not understand your point. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: The point is that the pre-compiler will actually elaborate on the `#` directives. If you have an `#else` in the multiline string it will break.

Comment: e.g. if you write `!Debug` in the first line, and then remove the `#endif` from within the string, then the compiler will parse the second `#if` and looks for its matching `#endif`

Comment: Also, your example works in post Rosyln compilers, but not with the Mono compiler that I am using.

Comment: @Lordalcol, Did not see any mono related tag. I just assumed you were using visual studio my bad :P